# Drupal 7 get localized taxonomy data in custom php code

Tags: php, drupal, internationalization, drupal-7

I'm working on a drupal site, and I need to have an information page for taxonomy data.

The taxonomy data has some extra fields that are displayed, including a custom link.

The default taxonomy page does not allow a custom link, and it will show the content assiociated to the term, I don't want that.

I made a module that outputs a block, and I'm basicly using this code

```
$term = taxonomy_term_load($termId);
```

This works fine, but I can't get the translated version of the taxonomy! I'm using the i18n module.

How can I get the localized version of the taxonomy?

Thanks in advance,

Jorik

Answer (score 7):

The langcode parameter of `taxonomy_term_view()` is used to filter by the language of associated nodes. it is (unfortunately?) not related to the language of the term itself.

You can get the i18n-localized term with

```
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
if (module_exists('i18n_taxonomy')) {
    module_load_include('inc', 'i18n', 'i18n_taxonomy.pages');
    $term = i18n_taxonomy_localize_terms($term);
}
print render(taxonomy_term_view($term, 'full'), $language->language);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to run your term object through [`taxonomy_term_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_view/7), that will build the view for you with a particular language code. You can get the 'current' language for the page using the global `$language` object:

```
global $language;
$term = taxonomy_term_load($termId);
$view = taxonomy_term_view($term, 'full', $language->language);
$html_output = render($view);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work! I'm using 'Localize. Terms are common for all languages, but their name and description may be localized.', when I'm going to the default taxonomy page it does work.. any idea why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip, as of writing the Views module doesn't fully support localized terms, as the default taxonomy pages do. You could check out http://drupal.org/project/i18nviews